# Inferring individual measurements from multiple sums of random samples

Tags: maximum-likelihood, inference

Given a set of approximately 100 equations, one for each sample $i \in [1, 100]$:
$$
 s_i = \sum_j c_{ij} p_j
$$
where $s_i$ is the known and positive sum for sample $i$, and $c_{ij}, j \in [1, 1000]$ is the known count of the $j$-th item in the $i$-th sample, how could one go about estimating the unknown positive factors $p_j$ (assumed constant across samples) for each item?

If it helps, I know that for most items $p_j$ is basically zero. In addition, I'm mostly interested in $p_j$ in order to identify the items for which $p_j$ is highest. The set of items from which each sample is drawn contains over 1,000 distinct items, but each sample can be assumed to contain only 100 items with a non-zero count $c_{ij}$.

It feels like this kind of problem where we have multiple aggregated statistics for samples of groups of objects, but no direct observations of the individual objects should be something that is commonly encountered in statistics and perhaps there are some specific strategies for tackling them.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem described is not well defined as it is unlikely there will be a unique solution. Consider the example below in R where $p_j\sim\text{Gamma}(0.2, 1)$, $c_{ij}-1\sim\text{NB}(1,0.1)$, and $a_{ji}=c_{ij}^T$.

```
set.seed(1461069042)
p <- rgamma(1e3, 0.2)
a <- matrix(0L, 1e3, 100)
a[matrix(c(mapply(sample, rep(1e3, 100), size = 100), rep(1:100, each = 100)), ncol = 2)] <- rnbinom(1e4, 1, 0.1) + 1L
# check that each column of a has 100 non-zero values
all(colSums(a > 0L) == 100L)
#> [1] TRUE
# check that each row has at least one non-zero value
all(rowSums(a > 0L) > 0L)
#> [1] TRUE
s <- colSums(p*a)
```

Use linear programming to produce three different vectors ($\vec{x}$) that each solve $s_i=\sum_{j}a_{ji}x_i$

```
library(lpSolve)
# minimize the objective function (sum of p)
x1 <- lp("min", rep(1, 1e3), t(a), rep("=", 1e2), s)$solution
# maximize the objective function (sum of p)
x2 <- lp("max", rep(1, 1e3), t(a), rep("=", 1e2), s)$solution
# minimize the objective function (sum of each p multiplied by a random uniform)
x3 <- lp("min", runif(1e3), t(a), rep("=", 1e2), s)$solution

all.equal(colSums(x1*a), s)
#> [1] TRUE
all.equal(colSums(x2*a), s)
#> [1] TRUE
all.equal(colSums(x3*a), s)
#> [1] TRUE
```

However, they correlate very poorly with $\vec{p}$:

```
cor(x1, p)
#> [1] 0.08542776
cor(x2, p)
#> [1] 0.03603903
cor(x3, p)
#> [1] 0.05867096

o <- order(p, decreasing = TRUE)
plot(1:1e3, p[o])
points(1:1e3, x1[o], col = "red")
points(1:1e3, x2[o], col = "blue")
points(1:1e3, x3[o], col = "green")
```

[image]